# Laravel not save boolean to Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I don't know why my boolean value not change or save to database

Here's my PostController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'post_title' => 'required|string|max:60',
            'post_slug' => 'required|string|unique:posts,post_slug',
            'post_thumbnail' => 'required',
            'post_excerpt' => 'required|string|max:500',
            'post_seq' => 'required',
            'post_description' => 'required|string',
            'post_meta_title' => 'required|string|max:60',
            'post_meta_description' => 'required|string|max:250',
            'post_meta_keyword' => 'required|string',
            'is_active' => 'required'
        ]);

        Post::create([
            'post_title' => $request->post_title,
            'post_slug' => $request->post_slug,
            'post_seq' => $request->post_seq,
            'post_thumbnail' => parse_url($request->post_thumbnail)['path'],
            'post_excerpt' => $request->post_excerpt,
            'post_description' => $request->post_description,
            'post_meta_title' => $request->post_meta_title,
            'post_meta_description' => $request->post_meta_description,
            'post_meta_keyword' => $request->post_meta_keyword,
            'created_by' => User::where('name')->get(),
            'is_active' => $request->has('is_active'),
            'user_id' => $request->user_id
        ]);
        Alert::success('Add Post', 'Added Post Success');
        dd($request->all());
        // return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
```

Here's my Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['post_title', 'post_slug', 'post_thumbnail', 'post_seq', 'post_excerpt', 'post_description', 'post_meta_title', 'post_meta_description', 'post_meta_keyword', 'is-active', 'created_by'];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $title)
    {
        return $query->where('post_title', 'LIKE', "%{$title}%");
    }
}
```

Here's my create.blade.php:

```
<!-- status -->
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('is_active') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <label>Is user active?</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="is_active" id="is_active">
         <option value="1" @if (old('is_active')==1) selected @endif>True</option>
         <option value="0" @if (old('is_active')==0) selected @endif>False</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

When i `dd($request->all());` it change or save to 1 when i choose True, but when i checked in my database, it still 0.

Comment: You have is-active in your fillable, it should be is_active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! In your `$fillable` you write `is-active` with a hyphen, but in your create method write `is_active` with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

look at your code

```
class Post extends Model
*is-active*
```

Model `is-active` is differenct with `create.blade.php` `is_active` file, please check.